# Unable to setup email with client with 2014 mac mini model

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, 23.10, email-client, mac-mini

I recently decided to repurpose my old 2014 mac mini (model A1347), by installing Debian 12 , deleting the old Mac OS that was on this device. Everything was going well until I was unable to use both evolution and thunderbird to setup my icloud, live (outlook), and proton.me accounts. I double checked login information several times, for all accounts and double checked the incoming and outgoing server names, port numbers, and connection security options. I ended up removing debian and installing the latest Ubuntu OS. I am currently still experiencing the same problems with both client programs. When attempting to setup my accounts with evolution, i run into the problem with sending/receiving as it continues to ask me for the password for authentication. For thunderbird, i am unable to successfully setup any account all as it tells me there is either an error with my credentials or settings. I also removed the device from my VPN momentarily to test the issue to no avail. Below are the specifications for this device:

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Macmini4,1
- **Memory:**                                      8.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™2 Duo P8600  × 2
- **Graphics:**                                    NVAF
- **Disk Capacity:**                               320.1 GB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            76.0.0.0.0
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               Not Available
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-15-generic

Has anybody experienced this similar issue?